# Retrieve specific value from Firebase database into string variable

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to retrieve a specific value from a Firebase realtime Database.

The data looks like this:

[image: The data looks like this;]

I want to get the URL value from any of them and then put it into a string variable to use later. This is so that the program does not need to be changed if the download link is changed. The code I have so far is;

```
DatabaseReference fdb = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
//Query query = fdb.child("URLDOWNLOADS").child("WSSeasons")
fdb.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot)
    {
        for (DataSnapshot url : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
        {
            LoginInfoFirebasedb DownURL = url.getValue(LoginInfoFirebasedb.class);
            String temp = DownURL.dwldURL;
            URL1 = temp;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError)
    {

    }
});
```

Some help would be seriously appreciated. I understand this may be a simple problem but I am stumped.

Comment: For your use case ("*the program does not need to be changed if the download link is changed*"), you might be better off using [Firebase Remote Config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config/) instead? This is exactly what Remote Config is geared towards.

Comment: @Grimthorr If I had more time I would look into it but as of now this was a minor problem and the solutions below solve it.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted. If you do implement Remote Config from the beginning, it can be very powerful to push changes like these to your app in the wild.

Comment: @Grimthorr thanks, I will keep that in mind for the next app I am working on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get each url as a String, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference ref = rootRef.child("URLDOWNLOADS");
ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String key = ds.getKey();
            String url = ds.child("URL").getValue(String.class);
            Log.d(TAG, key + " / " + url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Log.d(TAG, databaseError.getMessage()); //Don't ignore errors!
    }
};
ref.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: If you want to also get the key (`WSMagazine`, etc) then also print `ds.getKey()` in the loop.

Comment: Thanks, does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @AlexanderMcmichael Good to hear that. You're welcome, cheers!